# issue in encryption program program in c

Tags: c

I am trying to Encrypt what the user write base on 2 strings i already defined them

the program works well

but I have a problem when the user write more than 30 characters

at the end of  Encryption  some times the program appears random characters

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
  {

  char  read [120] ;
  char  Encryption [55] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
  char  Decryption [55] = {'k','K','f','z','L','S','j','T','v','u','B','F','q','U','P','h','n','M','i','Z','w','x','y','Y','W','t','m','s','N','J','Q','E','G','l','X','a','A','c','b','C','e','o','D','H','I','r','d','R','V','p','p','g'};
  char  new[120];
  int i , k;

  gets(read);

  for (i=0 ; i<strlen(read) ; i++)
  {
     for(k=0 ; k<strlen(Encryption) ; k++){
             if (read[i]==' ')  new[i]=' ';
             else if (read[i] ==  Encryption[k]){
                         new[i]=Decryption[k];}
                         }
             }


     puts(new);
     getch();

  }
```

for example when the user write ((( ALNOR ALNOR )))  output is (((kFUPM kFUPM )))

BUT WHEN i write ((( ALNOR ALNOR ALNOR ALNOR ALNOR ))) the out put should be ((( kFUPM kFUPM kFUPM kFUPM kFUPM ))) but what apears is ((( kFUPM kFUPM kFUPM kFUPM kFUPM H&M)))

i dont no from where H&M came and when i run it again H&M chaing to something else

???!!!

Comment: Put a '\0' at the end of your decrypted character array before printing it

Comment: Why did you tag this as `C++` when obviously it is `C`?

Comment: `char  new[120] = {0};`

Comment: If you tried to compile this as C++, you'd see one angry compiler... `char new[120]` <-- `new`??

Answer (score 0):

As 'Drax' indicated, the code needs to properly terminate the 'new' string. perhaps by inserting a line after the for loop:

```
  for (i=0 ; i<strlen(read) ; i++)
  {
     for(k=0 ; k<strlen(Encryption) ; k++){
             if (read[i]==' ')  new[i]=' ';
             else if (read[i] ==  Encryption[k]){
                         new[i]=Decryption[k];}
                         }
             }
  }

  new[i] = '\0';
```